# Why does my IIS virtual directory serve folders but not files?

Tags: 404, iis7, access-control

I have a network share (say, `\\mysite\myshare`) being served by an IIS 7.5 virtual 
directory at (say) http://www.example.com/myshare. From a web browser, I can click & navigate every folder and subfolder, but if I click *any file*, I get a 404 error (404.0):

```
2015-04-10 14:27:36 GET /myshare/folder1/42-19740409.jpg - - 11.22.33.44 HTTP/1.1
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:37.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/37.0
http://www.example.com/myshare/folder1/ 404 1437
```

Here is the corresponding log entry for browsing the folder, which succeeds:

```
2015-04-10 14:27:34 GET /myshare/folder1/ - - 11.22.33.44 HTTP/1.1
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:37.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/37.0
http://www.example.com/myshare/ 200 1225
```

The permissions on the network share seem fine. IIS is mounting the share as user "mynetwork\shareguy", and I can manually mount the share with these credentials and access all files and folders. There is also an application pool for mynetwork\shareguy.

My MIME Types setup seems OK too. There are tons of MIME types set up, including for .jpg files (my example above).

I also tried right-clicking on the virtual directory in IIS, then choosing "Manage Virtual Directory" and "Browse." I can browse all the folders via localhost in this manner, but again, every file produces a 404. But strangely, the error message shows **Logon Method** and **Logon User** as "anonymous." I would think it should say "shareguy".

```
Module: IIS Web Core 
Notification: MapRequestHandler 
Handler: StaticFile 
Error Code: 0x80070002 
Requested URL: http://localhost:80/... 
Physical Path \\myshare\myfolder\...
Logon Method: Anonymous 
Logon User: Anonymous
```

Why would all folders be accessible but none of the files? Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would highly recommend adding the sc-substatus field to the IIS log.  IIS recognizes about 20 different 404 variations that it identifies with the substatus field.  Look here for a complete list:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891